# Pass multiple string values to a parameter in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access parameter query and pass it a list of values to use in a `NOT IN` clause.

- When I pass the values in a parameter it seems to ignore it and
  return all records.
- When I pass the values as a variable embedded
  in the SQL it works correctly and returns the four records not
  mentioned in the `NOT IN` clause.

*So my question is:*  How do I pass multiple string values in a parameter?

The two tables used in the query are:

**HourlyRateTypes**  (only RateType is used from this table).

```
| ID | RateType | ShowOnTimeSheet | SortOrder | SuggestCalculation | Enabled | IsBaseRate |
|----|----------|-----------------|-----------|--------------------|---------|------------|
| 1  | Normal   | Yes             | 1         |                    | Yes     | Yes        |
| 2  | Flat     | Yes             | 2         | 1                  | Yes     | No         |
| 3  | x 1.5    | Yes             | 3         | 1.5                | Yes     | No         |
| 4  | x 2      | Yes             | 4         | 2                  | Yes     | No         |
| 5  | x 3      | Yes             | 5         | 3                  | Yes     | No         |
| 6  | Holiday  | Yes             | 6         | 1                  | Yes     | No         |
| 7  | Sick     | Yes             | 7         | 1                  | Yes     | No         |
| 8  | Furlough | No              | 8         | 1                  | No      | No         |
```

and **RoleHourlyRates**

```
| ID | RoleID | RateType | Rate   | EmployerID |
|----|--------|----------|--------|------------|
| 1  | 1      | 1        | £10.15 | 1          |
| 2  | 1      | 2        | £10.15 | 1          |
| 3  | 1      | 3        | £15.23 | 1          |
| 4  | 1      | 4        | £20.30 | 1          |
| 5  | 1      | 5        | £30.45 | 1          |
| 6  | 1      | 6        | £10.15 | 1          |
| 7  | 1      | 7        | £10.15 | 1          |
| 8  | 1      | 8        | £10.15 | 1          |
```

This version of the code returns all records rather than those not appearing in the ExcludeRecs parameter.

```
Public Sub ParamQueryTest()

    Dim pEmployerID As Long
    pEmployerID = 3
    
    Dim pRoleID As Long
    pRoleID = 1
    
    Dim pExclusionText As String
    pExclusionText = """Normal"", ""x 1.5"", ""x 2"", ""x 3""" 'Returns "Normal", "x 1.5", "x 2", "x 3"
    
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS ExcludeRecs Text (255), RoID Long, EmpID Long; " & _
        "SELECT HRT.RateType, Rate " & _
        "FROM   HourlyRateTypes HRT INNER JOIN RoleHourlyRates RHR ON HRT.ID = RHR.RateType " & _
        "WHERE  RHR.RoleID = RoID AND RHR.EmployerID = EmpID " & _
        "AND HRT.RateType NOT IN (ExcludeRecs)")
    qdf.Parameters("RoID") = pRoleID
    qdf.Parameters("EmpID") = pEmployerID
    qdf.Parameters("ExcludeRecs") = pExclusionText
    
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    
    With rst
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            Do
                Debug.Print .Fields("RateType"), .Fields("Rate")
                .MoveNext
            Loop While Not .EOF
        End If
    End With
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Normal         10.15 
Flat           10.15 
x 1.5          15.23 
x 2            20.3 
x 3            30.45 
Holiday        10.15 
Sick           10.15 
Furlough       10.15
```

This code returns the correct records - excluding Normal, x 1.5, x 2 and x 3:

```
Public Sub ParamQueryTest2()

    Dim pEmployerID As Long
    pEmployerID = 3
    
    Dim pRoleID As Long
    pRoleID = 1
    
    Dim pExclusionText As String
    pExclusionText = """Normal"", ""x 1.5"", ""x 2"", ""x 3""" 'Returns "Normal", "x 1.5", "x 2", "x 3"
    
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS RoID Long, EmpID Long; " & _
        "SELECT HRT.RateType, Rate " & _
        "FROM   HourlyRateTypes HRT INNER JOIN RoleHourlyRates RHR ON HRT.ID = RHR.RateType " & _
        "WHERE  RHR.RoleID = RoID AND RHR.EmployerID = EmpID " & _
        "AND HRT.RateType NOT IN (" & pExclusionText & ")")
    qdf.Parameters("RoID") = pRoleID
    qdf.Parameters("EmpID") = pEmployerID
    
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    
    With rst
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            Do
                Debug.Print .Fields("RateType"), .Fields("Rate")
                .MoveNext
            Loop While Not .EOF
        End If
    End With
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

---

```
Flat           10.15 
Holiday        10.15 
Sick           10.15 
Furlough       10.15
```

Comment: Table and field names and where/in clauses cannot be dynamic. Thus, your second attempt is the correct method.

Comment: No, you're not meant to say that....  you're meant to answer that I should use `'` instead or something like that.  I knew that table & field names cannot be changed in a parameter - having to do that would suggest to me that the database needs a redesign.  Didn't know you couldn't pass multiple values to an IN clause though.   That's a pain in the proverbial.

Comment: Why do you use a Query def in this case instead of sql statment like :  strSQL = "SELECT HourlyRateTypes.RateType, RoleHourlyRates.Rate FROM RoleHourlyRates INNER JOIN HourlyRateTypes ON RoleHourlyRates.RateType = HourlyRateTypes.Id"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((HourlyRateTypes.RateType)<>'Normal' And (HourlyRateTypes.RateType)<>'x 1.5' And (HourlyRateTypes.RateType)<>'x 2' And (HourlyRateTypes.RateType)<>'x 3'));"
'

Comment: @MathiasZ  The variables used in the code come from a userform.  The Employer and Role are from combo-boxes.  The exclusion list depends on the controls I put on the form - the controls in question have a tag of "HourlyRates" and the associated label is exactly as shown in the HourlyRateTypes.RateType field.  So my code uses the label captions to create the pExclusionText variable and pulls back any records for controls that dont appear, these are then shown as a ToolTip on an Extra Info icon.  If I need to add another pay type or include the control on the form I dont have to update the code.

Comment: In your second example you insert a text string in the query like the normal use. The first use a Parameter object. I only **suspect** that because an expression is required this is the reason.

Comment: I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I apply filter criteria to form or report. The first code builds an SQL with a simple string of characters (including quotes and commas) referenced in the IN() function, not an array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an individual parameter for each item in exclusion list.
Try something like this:

```
DIM ExclusionList , ParamsList() As String , i As Integer
ExclusionList= ARRAY("Normal" , "x 1.5" , "x 2" , "x 3")
REDIM ParamsList(UBOUND(ExclusionList))

FOR i= 0 To UBOUND(ExclusionList)
    ParamsList(i)= "@PRM" & TRIM(i+1) & " TEXT(255) "
NEXT

Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
          "PARAMETERS RoID Long , EmpID Long , " & JOIN(ParamsList , ",") & ";" & _
          "SELECT HRT.RateType, Rate " & _
          "FROM   HourlyRateTypes HRT INNER JOIN RoleHourlyRates RHR ON HRT.ID = RHR.RateType " & _
          "WHERE  RHR.RoleID = RoID AND RHR.EmployerID = EmpID " & _
          "AND HRT.RateType NOT IN (" & REPLACE(JOIN(ParamsList , ",") , " TEXT (255) " , VBNULLSTRING) & ")")

qdf.Parameters("RoID") = pRoleID
qdf.Parameters("EmpID") = pEmployerID
FOR i= 0 To UBOUND(ParamsList)
    qdf.Parameters("PRM" & TRIM(i+1))= ExclusionList(i)
NEXT
```

PS:
It's better to use RateID's instead of Rate Text.

EDIT:
The SQL text of the qdf query is as following:

```
PARAMETERS RoID Long , EmpID Long , @PRM1 TEXT(255) ,@PRM2 TEXT(255) ,@PRM3 TEXT(255) ,@PRM4 TEXT(255) ;
SELECT HRT.RateType, Rate FROM   HourlyRateTypes HRT 
       INNER JOIN RoleHourlyRates RHR ON HRT.ID = RHR.RateType 
WHERE  RHR.RoleID = RoID AND 
       RHR.EmployerID = EmpID AND 
       HRT.RateType NOT IN (@PRM1,@PRM2,@PRM3,@PRM4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Shahram.  That works - except you've not used the PRM parameters in the `NOT IN` clause, but have used the literals.  I swapped out `& JOIN(ExclusionList, ",") &` for `& Trim(Replace(Join(ParamsList, ","), " TEXT(255)", "")) &` and it still worked, so all good.  I'll edit my question with extra info for the solution once I've tidied the code up and got it all working.

Comment: I agree that using the ID would be better, but in this case the full code is working out what controls are on the user form and running two queries to return the values for the controls on the form and the values for those missing from the form.  It would be much easier for me to have static controls showing the four main rates of pay but where's the fun in easy?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: Thanks for the hint. I edited the code.